# Is there ever a case when IO exceptions are thrown?

Tags: java, exception, io

I have never seen any example where an IO Exception during java io operation was thrown. Each and every time I have seen it being caught. Is it true that for all practical purposes it never needs to be thrown ? If my answer to my previous question is untrue, then under which real life scenario is it ever `thrown` ?

Comment: Disk failure, FS corruption etc... Sh*t happens!

Comment: You seriously never seen an IO exception? You've never attempted to write to a file that doesn't exist, or had the connection to a remote sockets stream your writing to get severed unexpectedly? It just seems funny to me because I think I was barely into my first OOP courses in college when I first ran into them.

Comment: You seriously never seen an IO exception? I have seen it, but seen it getting caught, not getting thrown

Comment: I don't understand the distinction... what you do with a thrown exception is irelevent, the fact remains it must be thrown for it to be caught. Unless you mean you've only seen the catch statements, but were never able to reach them at runtime.. in which case I suggest trying to write to a file that's locked by another process, or one that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, say for example a user just clicked on a "Show Orders" button and here is the code:

```
List<Order> orders = getOrdersFromDatabase();
showOrdersInTable(orders);

public List<Order> getOrdersFromDatabase() throws IOException {... }
```

Unfortunately, some stupid guy just decided to cut the power cable of the server for fun (OK: he just got fired). The server running the database is now unreachable.

Your code can either:

- ignore the exception and your application will fail silently without anyone knowing what is going on
- let the exception propagate to your main without ever catching it and your application will crash miserably
- catch and handle the exception at an appropriate abstraction layer, where you can log the details of the error and warn the user: `showPopup("Sorry, the server xyz can't be reach right now, do you want to retry or abort?");`

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about `IOException` you also talk about all exceptions inherinting it. Among them, for instance, there is `FileNotFoundException` (old file API -- ditch) but also `ReadOnlyFilesystemException`, `NotDirectoryException`, `AccessDeniedException`, etc etc (new file API -- use).

Therefore, yes, a *lot* of `IOException`s are thrown, in fact.